# How to debug a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out error in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-rds, laravel-8, aws-aurora-serverless

**PHP:** 8.1.1
**Laravel:** 8.82
**Nova:** 3.31
**MySQL:** Serverless Aurora Mysql 5.7
**Hosting:** ECS/EC2 Linux 2

4-days ago, randomly and seemingly not linked to any specific update we started receiving the following errors in Sentry. Around 7 per hour, a small amount of our traffic and intermittent. It's coming from various routes and queries (updates, selects) and references our Serverless Aurora Mysql 5.7 connection which works correctly 99.9% of the time.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception
```

Any ideas or where to start debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `telescope` package?

Comment: Also recently I had similar issue, sometimes because of a long running query, tables get locked, so further queries that try to connect at that time gets timed out. When you receive the time out error, get the list of process inside mysql instance using `show processlist` and you might get to something.

Answer (score 1):

Still not entirely sure what happened here, but cloning the Serverless Aurora Mysql 5.7 database and routing the traffic to the new one seemed to solve the issue. Possibly there is an issue building in the background, but currently, this is working.

+++++++

The above worked for us, but AWS support got back to us with the following as well.

Cloning the database fixed this for us, as per the answer above. But AWS support loosely got back to us with the following if it helps.

Our service team have provided some reasons this error could appear, but cannot be confirmed since the cluster along with it's logs, metrics, and resources have already been deleted:

- Timeout settings on the client side
- Timeout setting on the DB side
- Connections have been exhausted on the DB and no new connections would be possible. Since Aurora Serverless scales automatically based on connections[1], it is possible that a scaling point[2] could not be found as connections increased which caused the max_connections to be reached.
- Resource contention on the cluster, such as CPU. Since Aurora Serverless scales automatically based on CPU Utilization[1] as well, it is possible that a scaling point[2] could not be found as CPU Utilization increased which could lead to timeouts.

Comment: Now that it's been a few months, I'm curious to know if you've run into this anymore since you've created the new db.

Comment: No more issues, everything is working as expected.